# center image in header

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am at the moment programming in the foundation framework. But I cannot understand why the picture in the yelllow menubar is left aligned? I would like the picture to be centered. I have tried everything in the documentation, but that is not working for me. Does anybody have any other suggestion?

[My Site Example](http://vouzalis.com/index.html)

```
<body>
  <table class="body">
    <tr>
      <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
        <center>

          <table class="row" style="background-color:yellow;">
            <tr>
             <td class="center" align="center">
             <center>
              <table class="container">
                <tr>
                  <td class="wrapper last">
                    <table class="twelve columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <img width="250" height="80" src="http://placehold.it/580x300">
                        </td> 
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br>

      <table class="container">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!-- content start -->
            <table class="row">
              <tr>
                <td class="wrapper last">
                  <table class="twelve columns">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <h1>Hi, Elijah Baily</h1>
                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.</p>
                        <img width="580" height="300" src="http://placehold.it/580x300">

                      </td>
                      <td class="expander"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your site example you have `body, table.body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, td` with property `text-align:left`. and get rid of of `display: block;
    float: left;` from your img class.

> Note that if you will make `text-align:center` it will affect the whole form. so make another class for it.

Comment: @Ne Kr its working. remove `img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
 }` from your `<img>` element and in the `<td>` above it add `text-align:center`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your site example, the `<img>` element has the following styles:

```
 img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
 }
```

Both these styles are causing the behaviour. First, the `display: block` makes the image element take up the full width of it's container, even if the image itself does not. Second the `float: left` moves the image to the left side of its container.

Remove both these styles and the image will be centered.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried to delete the `/*
img.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}
*/` , but the picture is still left aligned. I am just gonna upload the new code right now, to the address I gave in the question

Comment: You also have to remove the `display: block` style. Let me know when you've uploaded the new code

Comment: Just remove "twelve columns" class from header part of your html which wraps the logo and the logo will be centered.

Comment: The containing `td` element needs to specify that the content be center aligned. You can simply use `text-align: center`.

Comment: The problem was with the css you added in the table that wraps logo. There was no need to provide width if you wanted it to be centered. Remove the width and it will fix. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width part from this `css`:

```
table.container {
    /*width: 580px;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class as 'topImage' to the image and add following css to your css file:

```
.topImage {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: The Rahul's answer should work. Removing 'twelve columns' classes and no adding 'container' class neither